# Find out which characteristics to choose, based on the frequency measurement of characteristics of similar items

Tags: distributions, forecasting, frequency

I have this statistics oriented question and I need some input on the approach. There is a new product introduced, a contact lence that has seleral ranges of attributes (powers) from which the users can choose from:

```
Range A: [-0.1 to -4.00]
Range B: [-4.00 to -6.00] 
......
```

and I need to predict how many products of each power to order for the first time.

So, since it is a new product and there is no history of sales data I thought to run a query and get the sales volume of similar powers of simillar products, currently being sold.

After filtering the data I created in excel a frequency containing the sales volume for each power:

```
 Power | Frequency |
 -0.1  |    230    |
 -0.2  |    150    |
 -0.3  |    190    |
  .....
```

and I am stuck, how can I proceed from here to make the actual forecast? I am familiar with Linear regression but its not the case here as it's a different problem context and the data are not linear in the first place.

I know my questions are kinda theoritical but I dont know statistics and I need some starting point....

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can obtain a bigger sample or other information (variables) these values are your best guess for what you can expect to sell. However, this is not to say that they are very useful at all. If you want to do forecasting you will have to collect data over time (like monthly sales of each type over the past 5 years). But in your case I recommend you sample from different sources (if available) and collect other variables that might influence the number of sales (like marketing budget or price per unit) in order to model how many your company can expect to sell.